# Need to make unusual navigation work in all screen dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using somehwat unusual navigation, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAXhR.jpg). When a user mouses over the bars, they slide out into view.  All of that is working fine.  The problem is, I cannot find the CSS to make the buttons align left of the edge of the screen (as seen in the image), regardless of the display dimensions.

I originally tried:

```
<style>
#container {width: 600px; height: 25px; position: relative;} 
#bar0, #bar1, #bar2, #bar3, #bar4, #bar5 {position: absolute; left: -340px;}"; 
</style>
```

Which worked perfectly. But only on my screen. I thought that position:absolute inside position:relative would work regardless of screen dimensions, but was obviously wrong.

I then tried several variations on dynamically adjusting the screen width in container div with a function that runs onload:

```
function populateArrays() {                 
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    position[i] = -340; 
    bar[i] = document.getElementById("bar" + i.toString());
    id[i] = i; 
  }
    var sheet = document.createElement('style'); 
    var sWidth = screen.width; 
    sheet.innerHTML = "#container {width: " + sWidth + "px; height: 25px; position: relative;} #bar0, #bar1, #bar2, #bar3, #bar4, #bar5 {position: absolute; left: -340px;}"; 
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);           
}
```

But this also did not work.

*What is the **correct** way to align the images to the far left, partially (mostly) off screen, regardless of dimensions?*

**Thank you**

EDIT: HTML was requested. I don't know if this will help, the issue *seems* to be adjusting the CSS properly (perhaps with JavaScript).

```
<div id ="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="homeSilverGlassText.png" alt="Home" width="200" height="35" id="bar0" onmouseover="startMove(0)" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="aboutSilverGlassText.png" alt="Anout Me" width="200" height="35" id="bar1" onmouseover="startMove(1)" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="contactSilverGlassText.png" alt="Contact Me" width="200" height="35" id="bar2" onmouseover="startMove(2)" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="gallerySilverGlassText.png" alt="Gallery" width="200" height="35" id="bar3" onmouseover="startMove(3)" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="uiSilverGlassText.png" alt="Design" width="200" height="35" id="bar4" onmouseover="startMove(4)" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="editSilverGlassText.png" alt="Editor" width="200" height="35" id="bar5" onmouseover="startMove(5)" />
</div>
```

Links for button clicks have not yet been added.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your HTML code for the container and bars.

Comment: HTML is Posted.

Comment: That does not make it any less relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have what you want. Your code really doesn't do a great job of describing your problem though. You have images that are only 200px wide and you start by moving them 340px to the left so that you won't be able to see them at all. What are you trying to achieve with that? I'm not sure this is one hundred percent what you want, but this HTML/CSS will move half of your images off screen and then slowly (2 seconds) move them to a "normal" position on hover. I only moved them 100px offscreen so you can actually see them. Let me know if you are actually going for a different effect.

```css
#container {
 width: 600px;
 position: relative;
} 
.bar {
 position: absolute;
 transition: left 2s;
 left: -100px;
}
.bar:hover {
 left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x35" alt="Home" width="200" height="35" id="bar0" class="bar" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x35" alt="Anout Me" width="200" height="35" id="bar1" class="bar" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x35" alt="Contact Me" width="200" height="35" id="bar2" class="bar" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x35" alt="Gallery" width="200" height="35" id="bar3" class="bar" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x35" alt="Design" width="200" height="35" id="bar4" class="bar" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x35" alt="Editor" width="200" height="35" id="bar5" class="bar" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is similar to my effect, **thank you** very much. The only problem is... it still doesn't work across different browser dimensions. I've traced the problem with my code and your code down to the same thing: the "width:1024px;" in my body and main tags. 

The page looks ridiculous without constraining the width. I tried using % instead of pixels and have the same problem.  Is there a workaround for controlling page width which will allow me to use either my code or your code with width control?

Comment: The offset of the buttons is the concern. At a width of 1366 and an offset of -340, the buttons **don't** disappear, they're about 10% visible before they animate (that's exactly what I want). By using screen.width, there **should** be a way to adjust this offset dynamically, so that it's right for any size display. But I can't figure out the math...

Comment: Interestingly, 1366 (my screen width) - 1024 (my <body> and <main> width = 342. If I use "left: -342;" the result is perfect.  But screen.width - 1024 = leftOffset does **not** work at higher resolutions.  A resolution of 1600 requires "left: 460;" a resolution of 1920 requires "left: -620;".  So, I still haven't figured out the math needed to adjust for the <body> and <main> width throwing off my left alignment.

Comment: There is no width: 1024px tag in the code I created or the one you provided. If that was an integral part of your code to begin with, you should should have posted it. Probably right around the time I said "please post your HTML code".

Comment: Well, I didn't want to clutter this page, you didn't ask for CSS, so I didn't post it.  But yes, the style sheet is there, and has a width of 1024 in the body and main tags. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: These things happen. No harm, no foul. For your own good, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Now that everything is clear, I sure would appreciate if you, or someone, could explain the math to me that would fix this code.  These issues aren't random, there is a mathematical issue at work, I just don't know what it is.